# How to use NGIF for to display element into footer in dynamic datatable

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to display footer element in my row Datatable just if I'm in a specific column, I know how to do that in normal cases but here I use programming row def ( I should use it for grouping )

So I've tried that code:

Template:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index" matColumnDef="{{ column.field }}">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef (click)="SortWith($event,column)">{{ column.field }}


              </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <div >
                    {{ row[column.field] }}
                </div>
            </mat-cell>
            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef *ngIf="column.field == Category"> <b><font color=red>Total: </font></b></mat-footer-cell> // I need to dispaly this just in column of category

        </ng-container>

              <mat-header-row mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
              <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [className]="row.RemainingQuantities == 0 ? 'red' : 'redBack'"></mat-row>
              <mat-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-row>

              <!-- Group header -->
              <ng-container matColumnDef="groupHeader">
                  <mat-cell colspan="999" *matCellDef="let group">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="group.expanded">expand_less</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="!group.expanded">expand_more</mat-icon>
                      <strong>{{groupByColumns[group.level-1]}} = {{group[groupByColumns[group.level-1]]}} ({{group.totalCounts}})</strong>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

My component.ts:

```
this.columns = [{
      field: 'Category'
    },  {
      field: 'Model'
    },  {
      field: 'Reference'
    },  {
      field: 'Name'
    },  {
      field: 'RemainingQuantities'
    },  {
      field: 'Department.Name'
    },  {
      field: 'Supplier.Name'
    }];
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(column => column.field);
    this.groupByColumns = ['Category'];
 columnsToDisplay: string[] = ['Category', 'Model', 'Reference', 'Name', 'RemainingQuantities', 'Department.Name', 'Supplier.Name'];
   SortedColumns: string[] = [];
    this.service.get_product().subscribe((result : any)=>{
      this.listdata = result;

      this.decompersed = decrypt(result);
      console.log(this.decompersed);
      this.ProductList = this.decompersed;
      this.dataSource.data = this.addGroups(this.ProductList, this.groupByColumns);
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate.bind(this);
      this.dataSource.filter = performance.now().toString();
```

But I found that error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't have multiple template
>   bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("
>   ]*ngIf="column.field == Category"> Total: "):

and when I remove the NgIf I found that result:

[image]

Just I need the first total label

Comment: create running code here. it will helpful to solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is using `[className]="column.field == 'Category' ? 'nothing' : 'hidetool'"` and the hidetool class contains hide att.